# Ошибка Python (pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

```
import time
from pygame import mixer
import pygame
import pyglet
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import mixer

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(100)


mixer.music.load('D:\Programs\games\Python\Projects\MEDIA\Sm.ogg')
mixer.music.play(-1)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((10000, 10000))




while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode((10000, 10000))
            mixer.music.play(-1)
            
    pygame.display.update()
```

Текст ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programs\games\Python\Projects\PY FILES\StonsV2.py", line 14, in <module>
    mixer.music.load('D:\Programs\games\Python\Projects\MEDIA\Sm.ogg')
AttributeError: module 'mixer' has no attribute 'music'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from pygame import mixer
...
import mixer # <-- mixer из pygame теперь уже не виден как просто mixer

...
mixer.music.load('D:\Programs\games\Python\Projects\MEDIA\Sm.ogg')
mixer.music.play(-1)
```

Вы последним импортом перекрыли `mixer` из `pygame` каким-то другим `mixer`-ом, в котором видимо нет `music` и т.д. Используйте полное имя, начиная с `pygame`, как это у вас в коде выше сделано, чтобы питону было понятно, о каком миксере тут речь:

```py
pygame.mixer.music.load('D:\Programs\games\Python\Projects\MEDIA\Sm.ogg')
^^^^^^^
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
^^^^^^^
```